# Show that limit of a sequence goes to 0.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Assume that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f’(x) = 0$. Let $a_n = f(n +1) - f(n)$. Show that $\ lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0$.

I can’t seem to think how to even begin with this. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: Regarding the title of your question, the *limit* of the sequence doesn't go anywhere, it *is* zero. It's the *sequence* that goes to the limit.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = \lim_ {n\to\infty} \frac{f(n + 1) - f(n)}{n + 1 - n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} f'(n + \xi) = \lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x) = 0
$$

where in the first step we use the definition of $a_n$, in the second step we use the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) with $\xi \in (0, 1)$ and in the third step we notice that $x = n + \xi$ tends to infinity when $n$ tends to infinity.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, I understand now.

Comment: Hey! For using MVT don’t we need continuity of the function as well? How do I use it here without that?

Comment: Well, it isn't stated explicitly, but $\lim_{x\to\infty} f’(x) = 0$ suggests the function is differentiable on some interval $(b, +\infty)$ over which the limit is taken. Differentiability implies continuity.

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n+1)-f(n)$ can be shown as $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}[f'(x)+f'(x+1/n)+f'(x+2/n)+...+f'(x+1)]$ which is $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}(n \times0)=1\times0=0.$

Comment: Can you please explain how to show that the second line?

Comment: $f'(n)$ is defined as $\lim_{x\to\infty}n(f(n+1/x)-f(n)$ so it adds up as $f(n+1+1/x)-f(n)$. As $1/x$ is zero it can be simplified to $f(n+1)-f(n)$.

Comment: thanks this also a nice way to do it